# Blocking screen rotation - Android

Tags: java, android, screen

I would like to keep the screen in a portrait position and not allowed screen rotation in my app. How should I do that ?

Comment: Here is how you disable landspace http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2014/06/activity-screen-rotationorientation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recall two ways, either try putting a ScreenOrientation in your manifest :

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait" // OR "landscape"
```

Or just do the following in code :

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); // ORActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
```